# Passing in a param in setState within React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  handleUpdateRingers(index, event) {

    this.setState({
      items: update(this.state.items, {0: {ringerNumbers: {$set: event.target.value}}})
    }, () => this.updateTotals())
```

How can I remove that hardcode of `0` in the setState and use the index to drive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for use `index` as `Object` key wrap to braces:

```
handleUpdateRingers(index, event) {

    this.setState({
      items: update(this.state.items, {[index]: {ringerNumbers: {$set: event.target.value}}})
    }, () => this.updateTotals())
```

Comment: than please mark answer as correct :)